# Create example simple with MVC Java

Tags: java, model-view-controller

I have a simple example to check login of user using MVC Model..

LoginModel:

```
public class LoginModel {
private String username;
private String password;

public LoginModel()
{        
}
/**
 * @return the username
 */
public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}
/**
 * @param username the username to set
 */
public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
/**
 * @return the password
 */
public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}
/**
 * @param password the password to set
 */
public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}
```

}

LoginView:

```
public class LoginView {
LoginModel user;

//Ham khoi tao cho LoginView
public LoginView(LoginModel user)
{
  this.user=user;
}

public void showMessage(String msg)
{
  System.out.println(msg);
}

public void getUserInfo()
{
try
{

    DataInputStream input=new DataInputStream(System.in);
    System.out.println("Username:");
    user.setUsername(input.readUTF());
    System.out.println("Password:");
    user.setPassword(input.readUTF());
    input.close();
}
catch(IOException e)
{
    System.out.println(e);
}
```

}
}

LoginControl:

```
public class LoginControl {
LoginModel user;
LoginView view;

public LoginControl(LoginModel user,LoginView view)
{
    this.user=user;
    this.view=view;
    while(true)
    {
    view.getUserInfo();
    if(checkLogin())
    {
        view.showMessage("Success");
    }
    else
    {
        view.showMessage("Wrong username or password");
    }
    }
}

private boolean checkLogin()
{
    if((user.getUsername().equals("sa"))&&(user.getPassword().equals("sa")))
    {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

}

LoginMain:

```
public class LoginMVC {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    LoginModel user=new LoginModel();
    LoginView view=new LoginView(user);
    LoginControl control=new LoginControl(user, view);
}
```

}

But when I run main class,It's only username: and input user and stop..
I don't known where is error.
Can you help me.

Comment: Is there a reason you're using `DataInputStream` rather than `Scanner` for reading user input?

Comment: U can use Scanner rather than using the Depricated Api DataInputStream

Comment: +1 your MVC is correct. happy coding.

Comment: After searching for several hours for getting started with simple example for MVC, I found this great example. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure why `DataInputStream` is not working, I suggest to use [Scanner](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) for getting input from console in `getUserInfo` method.

```
  Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Username:");
  user.setUsername(scanner.nextLine());
  System.out.println("Password:");
  user.setPassword(scanner.nextLine());
  scanner.close();
```

Comment: @Vulcan thanks. you edited before I commit editing :-) thanks.